# Why does my touchscreen stop working when I unplug the wireless mouse?

Tags: windows-10

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior recently.

I started using a wireless Logitech mouse about 3 weeks ago and for some reason, when I disconnect the mouse (unplug the usb) the touchscreen stops working. when I re-plug it in again, it starts functioning again! What does the touchscreen have any relation to the Logitech mouse is mind boggling to me!

Before I got the Logitech mouse, the touchscreen worked just fine. However, recently the touchscreen and even fingerprint reader stopped working "randomly" and I thought "meh, this is probably one of those annoying driver problems that randomly occur", but nothing was showing as problematic in the drivers...eventually, I started realizing that there is a relation between the Logitech mouse and the touchscreen! and even the fingerprint reader (sometimes it seems).

Any idea what may be happening here?

Comment: Do you have any Logitech specific software installed, or just the generic USB mouse drivers? In Device Manager's "View by connection", are the touchscreen and the fingerprint reader listed as connected via (internal) USB or something else?

Comment: What model mouse and which driver are you using?

Comment: @harrymc it's the mx900

Comment: Try the [Logitech Firmware Update Tool](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035037273). Which Logitech software have you installed on Windows?

Comment: @harrymc I didn't install it myself, just plugged it in and the magic happened behind the scenes 

Comment: You will find more software at my link. I suggest to install as much as is pertinent.

Comment: @harrymc it says There are no Downloads for this Version.

Comment: Is it an old mouse?

Comment: @harrymc it's the mx900, it's like 2 years old

Comment: Does it happen with another mouse? If not, then this might be a hardware problem that causes a strange effect in Windows.

Comment: @harrymc I can try it, just gotta find another wireless mouse